# python List of dict to dict of dict of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to format a data structure to my need. From a list of dict i want to create a dict of dict of a list.
Based on that data structure :

```
[{'accuracy': 0.04584040881114014,
  'epoch': 0,
  'loss': 3.908684137519228,
  'name': 'test14',
  'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
  'val_loss': 3.8432216644287114},
 {'accuracy': 0.1612903245539738,
  'epoch': 1,
  'loss': 3.8308442072066873,
  'name': 'test14',
  'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
  'val_loss': 3.4720854759216313},
 {'accuracy': 0.056027164736506485,
  'epoch': 0,
  'loss': 3.9064058800099866,
  'name': 'test15',
  'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
  'val_loss': 3.8064255714416495},
 {'accuracy': 0.16129032566713356,
  'epoch': 1,
  'loss': 3.7856348285448367,
  'name': 'test15',
  'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
  'val_loss': 3.5590925216674805}]
```

i would like to achieve something like that:

```
    {'test14': [{'accuracy': 0.04584040881114014,
       'epoch': 0,
       'loss': 3.908684137519228,
       'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
       'val_loss': 3.8432216644287114},
      {'accuracy': 0.1612903245539738,
       'epoch': 1,
       'loss': 3.8308442072066873,
       'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
       'val_loss': 3.4720854759216313}],
     'test15': [{'accuracy': 0.056027164736506485,
       'epoch': 0,
       'loss': 3.9064058800099866,
       'name': 'test15',
       'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
       'val_loss': 3.8064255714416495},
      {'accuracy': 0.16129032566713356,
       'epoch': 1,
       'loss': 3.7856348285448367,
       'name': 'test15',
       'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
       'val_loss': 3.5590925216674805}]}

So far I succeed to have something like that :

{'test14': {'accuracy': 0.1612903245539738,
  'epoch': 1,
  'loss': 3.8308442072066873,
  'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
  'val_loss': 3.4720854759216313},
 'test15': {'accuracy': 0.16129032566713356,
  'epoch': 1,
  'loss': 3.7856348285448367,
  'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
  'val_loss': 3.5590925216674805}}
```

Using that piece of code :

```
for entry in data:
         name = entry.pop('name')
         n_dict[name] = entry
```

But it is note taking all the value. It only takes one dictionnary per key. I am clearly missing something here. Could you light me on this ?

Comment: You don't want to use `pop()` unless you want to remove the value from the old dict. Just access the value normally with `name = entry['name']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using a defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_dict = defaultdict(list) # New entries will automatically be empty lists
for data_dict in old_list: # Cycle through your old data structure
    new_dict[data_dict['name']].append(data_dict) # Append to the list in the defaultdict with the key testname
```

This yields:

```
defaultdict(list,
        {'test14': [{'accuracy': 0.04584040881114014,
           'epoch': 0,
           'loss': 3.908684137519228,
           'name': 'test14',
           'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
           'val_loss': 3.8432216644287114},
          {'accuracy': 0.1612903245539738,
           'epoch': 1,
           'loss': 3.8308442072066873,
           'name': 'test14',
           'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
           'val_loss': 3.4720854759216313}],
         'test15': [{'accuracy': 0.056027164736506485,
           'epoch': 0,
           'loss': 3.9064058800099866,
           'name': 'test15',
           'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
           'val_loss': 3.8064255714416495},
          {'accuracy': 0.16129032566713356,
           'epoch': 1,
           'loss': 3.7856348285448367,
           'name': 'test15',
           'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
           'val_loss': 3.5590925216674805}]})
```

Comment: Thanks a for that !

Answer (score 2):

You overwrite your data - you need to add to it:

> ```
> for entry in data:
>      name = entry.pop('name')
>      n_dict[name] = entry  # this overwrites the value of name all the time
> ```

Fix:

```
n_dict = {}
for entry in data:
     name = entry.pop('name')
     n_dict.setdefault(name,[])
     n_dict[name].append(entry)
```

(or use a [defaultdict from collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)) which is more effective then using `dict.setdefault(...)` - but for your datasample both should work.

---

Output:

```
{'test15': [{'loss': 3.9064058800099866, 'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
             'epoch': 0, 'val_loss': 3.8064255714416495, 
             'accuracy': 0.056027164736506485}, 
            {'loss': 3.7856348285448367, 'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782,
             'epoch': 1, 'val_loss': 3.5590925216674805, 
             'accuracy': 0.16129032566713356}], 
 'test14': [{'loss': 3.908684137519228, 'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782, 
             'epoch': 0, 'val_loss': 3.8432216644287114, 
             'accuracy': 0.04584040881114014}, 
            {'loss': 3.8308442072066873, 'val_accuracy': 0.1878172606229782, 
             'epoch': 1, 'val_loss': 3.4720854759216313, 
             'accuracy': 0.1612903245539738}]}
```

Comment: Thank you also for this explanation !